# Lagrange Multiplier in 3D

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Find the minimum and maximum values of the function $f(x,y,z) = x+2y+3z$ where $(x,y,z)$ is on the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ using Lagrange multiplier.

So I put them into the Lagrange form and got 
$L(x,y,z,\lambda) = x+2y+3z+ \lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$
And you then get simultaneous equations
$L_x = 1+ 2\lambda x$,
$L_y = 2+ 2\lambda y$,
$L_z = 3+ 2\lambda z$,
$L_\lambda = x^2 +y^2 + z^2-1$.

However, when I solved these simultaneously, I got some very strange solutions, so I don't know if I've done something wrong up to this point on my solving was wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$x+2y+3z\leq\sqrt {x^2+y^2+z^2}\sqrt {1+4+9} = \sqrt {14}$, by Cauchy-Schwarz, so $\max$ occurs at $x = \dfrac{y}{2} = \dfrac{z}{3} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{14}}$ and $\min$ occurs at $x = \dfrac{y}{2} = \dfrac{z}{3} = -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{14}}$. 
You should get a same answer if you solve the Lagrange equations correctly.

Comment: Except that 1+4+9=14 not 10!

Answer (score 1):

I do not see strange results. Using the derivatives with respect to $x,y,z$, you then have $$x=-\frac{1}{2 \lambda }\qquad y=-\frac{1}{\lambda }\qquad  z=-\frac{3}{2 \lambda }$$ So $$L_\lambda=\frac{7}{2 \lambda ^2}-1=0$$ which makes $$ \lambda=\pm \sqrt{\frac{7}{2}}$$ Replacing, you then have $$x=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}\qquad y=\pm\frac{2}{\sqrt{14}}\qquad z=\pm\frac{3}{\sqrt{14}}$$ to which correspond values of $\pm \sqrt{14}$.

Comment: It might be good to clarify that the signs of $x$, $y$ and $z$ must agree.